# Prevent form submission on wrong captcha value

Tags: forms, captcha, form-submit

Hi i used a basic captcha script as below . The problem i am facing is that , inspite of wrong captcha value, the form is submitted . I need to prevent the form from submission if the value of Captcha is entered wrong .

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $hash = (!empty($_POST['hash'])) ? preg_replace('/[\W]/i', '', trim($_POST['hash'])) : ''; // Remove any non alphanumeric characters to prevent exploit attempts
  $captchacode = (!empty($_POST['captchacode'])) ? preg_replace('/[\W]/i', '', trim($_POST['captchacode'])) : ''; // Remove any non alphanumeric characters to prevent exploit attempts
  // function to check the submitted captcha
  function captchaChars($hash)
  {
    //  Generate a 32 character string by getting the MD5 hash of the servers name with the hash added to the end.
    //  Adding the servers name means outside sources cannot just work out the characters from the hash
    $captchastr = strtolower(md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $hash));
    $captchastr2 = '';
    for($i = 0; $i <= 28; $i += 7)
    {
      $captchastr2 .= $captchastr[$i];
    }
    return $captchastr2;
  }
  if(!empty($captchacode))
  {
    if(strtolower($captchacode) == captchaChars($hash))  // We convert submitted characters to lower case then compare with the expected answer
    {
      echo '<h3>The submitted characters were correct</h3>';

    }
    else
    {
      echo '<h3>The submitted characters were WRONG!</h3>';
       return true;
    }

  }

  else
  {
    echo '<h3>You forgot to fill in the code!</h3>';
    return true;
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code for the form processor?  What you have posted isn't enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had Captcha up and running on my website and it did nothing to prevent spam. It has been compromised as a spam prevention mechanism I'm afraid.

Besides that, you need to return false if the captcha is incorrect and the form will not be submitted.

Comment: Which condition is it falling into?